# How to verify installed packages

Tags: authentication, linux, digital-signature

On Linux (Debian x64) I recently installed some software with:

```
apt-get install the_package_name
```

APT told me some packages couldn't be authenticated but I ignored the warning and installed anyway.
Now I want to check if the installed packages are valid. Is it possible to check authenticity of 'installed' packages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's most likely already answered [here on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/124151/check-integrity-of-debian-system-after-possible-rootkit) or [here on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115415/verifying-debian-ubuntu-packages-integrity-when-booting-from-a-read-only-dvd)

Comment: Yup, this has devolved into "My apt-get packages didn't install correctly" (see comment thread on the Answer). Closing seems right. Asker can repost in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) gives a pretty good explanation. In particular, [this section](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_manually_check_for_package.27s_integrity) talks about how to verify packages.

In a nutshell when you install packages your system check that they are signed with a known key, using public key crypto. This guarantees that the packages come from a "trusted" source. In your case some packages were signed with an unknown key and you chose to ignore that warning.

To answer your question I'd recommend to let the system do all the authenticity checks; it's a job computers do much better than humans. All you have to do once is to make sure that your keys are the correct ones.

Please note that my explanation is an over-simplification and that I use the word "trust" loosely; a "trusted" source is a source that keeps their secret key secure. If a malicious attacker were to lay hands on Debian's secret key for package signing there's a much bigger problem than yours.

Comment: When I tried to install another software I got the same warning and then I used some commands like: apt-key update ... then the problem solved and the software installed without a warning. I suspect if I had done this before installing the first software that would have been installed without warning too. What do you think?

Comment: Verifications can fail if your local cache of the certificates are too old (typically a couple of days for most Public-Key-Infrastructures) because it's possible that certificates have been revoked in the meantime. It sounds like updating your Revocation Lists made the warnings go away.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth can I say a way to verify the packages is to reinstall them with repeating the command 'apt-get install' so that apt tries to install them and if new package is same as the old one it says 'you have already newest version'. Because now I updated the keys, can this way do what I want or it just checks the version number?

Comment: @lorenzog 
'To answer your question I'd recommend to let the system do all the authenticity checks'
I didn't find in page you addressed, a way to make the system 'do all the checks'. In fact this is exactly what I want but I don't know how to do it now.

Comment: A quick google of "apt-get verify installed packages" found an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9463/what-is-the-apt-equivalent-to-rpm-v-verify-installed-packages and here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1646925

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I'll check it now and write the result.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth debsums -c shows reports like this:
"debsums: missing file /usr/share/grabber/spider.pyc". All the output includes line like this nothing else. So are the packages valid? (This command supposed to show list of changed (invalid) packages)

Comment: another way using yum: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122681/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-package-is-installed-via-yum-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @George That post seems to explain just list the already install packages with 'yum' not verify them.

Comment: @user2808671 That tells you that `debsums` is not installed correctly. That doesn't tell you anything about whether the packages are valid or not :(

Comment: @user2808671 by 'letting the system do all the checks' I meant just to keep the keystore up to date and don't ignore/force anything.